# Dual National Aus/UK holidaying in Bali

Tags: dual-nationality

I am a dual national. Australian local but have a current UK passport. My Australian passport expired a month ago. Have travelled between Australian and UK a few times without any problem but...

Going for a brief trip (6 days) to Bali next month, can I leave and re-enter Australia using only the UK passport? I can show them my recently expired Aus passport and I have a return ticket.

Would prefer not to pay the extra to have my Aus passport renewed if not absolutely necessary!

Answer (score 2):

According to [Smartraveller](http://smartraveller.gov.au/tips/dual-nationals.html) (official Australian Government site):

> All Australians, including dual nationals, should leave and enter Australia on their Australian passport. If you have a passport from another country you can use that for travel once you have left Australia.
>
> People trying to enter Australia as an Australian citizen but without an Australian passport will face difficulties and delays. An Australian passport is the preferred and most conclusive proof of Australian citizenship when travelling.

Since Australia has exit passport checks, the first difficulty you might face is *leaving* Australia using a UK passport. Since the last time you entered Australia you probably used your Australian passport, they will not have any record of your UK passport having entered.

Comment: Hi Greg, I did consider this scenario but was hoping that just having the expired passport on me would be proof enough. Its a 6 day trip, I'd hope that the customs staff would understand the situation.

Comment: @Jarrad: Unfortunately I couldn't find any information about whether an expired passport is sufficient evidence or not for Australia. For the UK an expired passport is sufficient; other countries such as the US require a valid passport.

Comment: I appreciate it anyway. I have time to find an answer. I don't mind a delay or 2 but would be very disappointed to be barred re-entry based after being away for a week.

Comment: The US will admit citizens with expired passports, after an obligatory lecture from an annoyed CBP officer...